# How can I open ".scpt" files on Windows?

Tags: windows, file, download, applescript

I would like to open a ".scpt" file, what editors can I use?

P.S. I am using Windows, so the App should support Windows.

Comment: `scpt` files mostly belong to AppleScript. Since this extension is basically `text` you can open it with any editor of your choice.

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi, RE: "`scpt` files mostly belong to AppleScript. Since this extension is basically `text` you can open it with any editor of your choice." --  **AppleScript** `.scpt` _files_ are compiled and **are not** just basically _text_, and as such opening them in an app that cannot decompile them one will not be able to do much of anything with them on **Windows**. Sure there are _text strings_ that are readable but maybe not to the degree one might fully understand what the _script_ actually does. As an example, can one tell what this is doing?, https://i.imgur.com/zqDbgG8.png No!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, `.scpt` files are compiled versions of your script.  Save your script as a `.applescript` (i.e. TEXT) file if you want to edit your script on a machine without AppleScript.

Comment: That does not help if only Windows is available.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: A compiled AppleScript is mainly gibberish if you try to read it directly, and it only functions through the Apple Events IPC system built into the MacOS. If one only has access to Windows, one doesn't need and can't use AppleScript. This is like asking how you can sail a boat without any water.